# Should we have a PID tag?

Tags: discussion

There are [quite some questions on PID tuning or PID tuning related questions](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=pid).

Should we have a [pid](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pid) to make this more visible?

Or, should we tag such questions by adding the [heat-management](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat-management)?

Answer (score 1):

if we add it to the core of [heat-management](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat-management), we should alias [pid](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pid) to [heat-management](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heat-management).